# Comfirmation of Existence of finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

It has been known that for any prime number $p$ and any positive integer $n$, there exists a finite field $F$ with $|F|=p^n$. But is there any way we can find what exactly this $F$ (up to isomorphism) is?

Comment: Yes:  it is the quotient of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ by an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$.  And there is only one iso type.

Comment: @Randall, that's mean we know $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^3)$ is certainly not isomorphic to $Z_8$ right?

Comment: @LingMinHao $x^3$ is reducible. Also, $\mathbb Z_8$ is not the same as $\mathbb F_8$.

Comment: @Randall, is there any source that I can find the proof of your statement?

Comment: @LingMinHao  it's in nearly every intro algebra/rings book.

Comment: @Randall, you mean the uniqueness of two isomorphic fields of order $p^n$ and existence of finite field of every prime power $p^n$?

Comment: Yes.  Given two such fields $E$ and $F$, you show each are isomorphic to the same quotient by a polynomial ring.  By transitivity, $E$ and $F$ are iso.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer.